# Finding the concentration of a solution

Tags: concentration

Q.) Determine the concerntration of a solution made by dissolving 10.0g of sodium chloride in 750.0ml of solution.

I did the following; 1mol of sodium chloride = 58.44

- 58.44*10 - 584.4g
- Concentration = number of moles/volume
- 584.4/0.750 = 779.2 - and this is the wrong answer.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Rather than doing operations on just the numbers, also pay attention to the *units*; carry them along in your calculations. Do you see any mistakes?

Comment: I should have divided - 10/58.44 and then divided that by .750 - thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The molar mass $M$ of $\ce{NaCl}$ is $58.44\ \mathrm{\frac{g}{mol}}$ indeed:

$\displaystyle\text{molar mass}(\ce{NaCl}) = \frac{\text{mass}}{\text{amount of substance}} = 58.44\ \mathrm{\frac{g}{mol}}$

$\displaystyle\Rightarrow \text{amount of substance} = \frac{\text{mass}}{\text{molar mass}}=\frac{10.0\ \mathrm g}{58.44\ \mathrm{\frac{g}{mol}}} \approx 0.171\ \mathrm{mol}$

$\displaystyle\text{concentration} = \frac{\text{amount of substance}}{\text{volume}}=\frac{0.171\ \mathrm{mol}}{0.75\ \mathrm L}=0.228\ \mathrm{\frac{mol}{L}}$

Assumptions: Adding $\ce{NaCl}$ to these $750\ \mathrm{ml}$ does NOT change the volume noteworthy.